# Ruby equivalent for php function openssl_pkey_get_public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, openssl

I have the php script where the password encoding done using the 
openssl:

$key = openssl_get_publickey($certificate);
openssl_public_encrypt($pass,$userPassCrypted,$key,OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
openssl_free_key($key);

Now I trying to make the same with ruby

require 'openssl' 
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(certificate)
public_key = cert.public_key
passwordSSL = public_key.public_encrypt(password, 1)

The problem here is that these password encoding isn't match

The certificate the same but the public key 
in PHP is:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- 
... 
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

in ruby is:

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- 
... 
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

I guess here is the difference (keys body also not the same)...

How can I get inside ruby the same public key as in PHP? Or is it 
possible convert RSA key by somehow?

Or maybe I have to do it with another way?

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can open this by using the following:

```
# Public key
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/path/to/public/key"))

# Private key (with password)
private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/path/to/private/key), "password")
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**: Ah, okay. Yeah, I don't think there is a way to remove the " RSA " from the OpenSSL output without removing it with a regular expression.

```
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("/path/to/x509/cert"))

cert.public_key.to_s.gsub(/RSA PUBLIC KEY-----/, "PUBLIC KEY-----")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one won't help.  
If you look carefully so you will see that at the beginning I have the X509 certificate... So I have neither public key nor private just certificate...

Moreover your solution will also give me RSA key...  
cert.public_key  == OpenSSL::PKey::RSA  I guess

Comment: No... Just removing also will not work because the keys body not the same.   PUBLIC KEY and RSA PUBLIC KEY completely different keys...